# Diferença entre datas

Tags: javascript, data

Sempre que passo a diferença de datas no mesmo mês, dá certo, mas quando é entre meses diferentes, vem um valor negativo. Como eu faço uma diferença entre datas? Veja o meu código. O erro está em `total`

**Código**

```
if (($("#txtDateStart").val().split("/") == "") && ($("#txtDateEnd").val().split("/") == "")) {
    data1 = new Date();
    data2 = new Date();
}
else {
    var dtInicio = $("#txtDateStart").val().split("/");
    var dtFim = $("#txtDateEnd").val().split("/");
    data1 = new Date(dtInicio[2] + "/" + dtInicio[1] + "/" + dtInicio[0]);
    data2 = new Date(dtFim[2] + "/" + dtFim[1] + "/" + dtFim[0]);
}
var total = data2.getDate() - data1.getDate();
```

Comment: Peguei esse código e funcionou. var total = (((Date.parse(data2)) - (Date.parse(data1))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

Comment: Para 'finalizar' a pergunta, poste sua resposta e/ou forneça feedback com a razão de as respostas dos colegas não terem funcionado pra você.

Comment: Ainda não conseguiu a resposta?

Comment: Porque você ainda não escolheu uma resposta?

Answer (score 19):

Me baseei numa das melhores [respostas do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15289883/916193) e apliquei ao seu caso concreto:

```
if ( ($("#txtDateStart").val().split("/") == "") &&
     ($("#txtDateEnd").val().split("/") == "") ) {
   data1 = new Date();
   data2 = new Date();
}
else {
   var dtInicio = $("#txtDateStart").val().split("/");
   var dtFim = $("#txtDateEnd").val().split("/");
   data1 = new Date(dtInicio[2] + "/" + dtInicio[1] + "/" + dtInicio[0]);
   data2 = new Date(dtFim[2] + "/" + dtFim[1] + "/" + dtFim[0]);
}
var total = dateDiferencaEmDias( data1, data2 );

// a e b são objetos Date do JS
function dateDiferencaEmDias(a, b) {
   // Descartando timezone e horário de verão
   var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
   var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

   return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Exemplo:**

```
date1 = new Date('2014/01/01');
date2 = new Date('2014/04/01');
var diferenca = Math.abs(date1 - date2); //diferença em milésimos e positivo
var dia = 1000*60*60*24; // milésimos de segundo correspondente a um dia
var total = Math.round(diferenca/dia); //valor total de dias arredondado
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var total = (((Date.parse(data2)) - (Date.parse(data1))) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: Qual a diferença da sua solução para a solução dos colegas: [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13054/2998) e [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13050/2998)? Que te levou a postar uma nova resposta ao invés de marca a possivel resposta que lhe ajudou como correta?

Comment: @Fernando, acho que você não leu os posts. Apenas pegou uma resposta minha agora e comentou. Leia antes tudo, horário e etc e depois poste seu comentário. Veja o que me levou a responder agora. Está aí em algum lugar.

Comment: @Fernando uma diferença, por exemplo, é que essa aqui não leva em conta peculiaridades de timezone. Imagino que em dia que tenha mudança de horário de verão, por exemplo, o resultado possa ter uma variação indevida.

Comment: @pnet, li sim! Afinal não post e não comento algo sem ler! E só questionei a diferença entre sua solução e as demais, pois considerei as demais até mais completas e abrangente que a sua, pois como o Bacco comentou tratam timezone, dias negativos, já a sua não. Então gostaria de saber quais os problemas das demais que te levaram a não escolhe-las como resposta e ter a necessidade de postar outra resposta que não apresenta nada relativamente novo em relação as demais pois a formula de multiplicar a diferença pelos dias, minutos, segundos e milissegundos já está presente nas demais respostas?

Comment: @Fernando, eu ainda não marquei nenhuma resposta, não sei porque você está assim. Posso sim marcar uma outra, que não seja a minha, não vejo problema nisso. Como a solução à época estava num comentário e não mais abri essa página, nem me ative as respostas que foram dadas depois. Recebi a comunicação pelo SOpt do Anderson Madeira que estava questionando que eu havia comentado a solução, mas não havia finalizado e como procuro sempre finalizar, ainda que exista algumas perguntas abertas ainda, fui e respondi, mas não finalizei.