# Calcular diferença entre duas datas para validar campos da data

Tags: javascript, data

Precisava de arranjar um mecanismo para limitar uma pesquisa nunca superior a 3 meses.

Tenho duas datas, quero validar se estão dentro dos parâmetros definidos.

tenho este codigo() estou a usar o type date e o datepicker para correr em varios browsers

```
  <script src="data/js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                       <script type="text/javascript">
                    $("#pesquisa").on("submit", function (event) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                     var start= new Date(document.getElementById("datainicio").value);
                       var end = new Date(document.getElementById("datafim").value);
                    var dr    = moment.range(start, end);

                    dr.diff('months'); // 3
                    dr.diff('days'); // 92
                   alert( dr.diff();) // 7945200000

                  //   mostrarinfo();
            });
```

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13046/227

Comment: ja tive e ver mas não funca

Comment: Pra melhor ajudar os colegas a te responderem, tente explicar o que já tentou. Forneça códigos de exemplo de tentativas que fez e onde ou o quê não está dando certo.

Comment: para já tenho só isto, já vou buscar os campos   var dateinicio= document.getElementById("datainicio");
                            var datafim = document.getElementById("datafim");
                            
                            var datestart= new Date();
                            var dateend= new Date();

Comment: Para resolver isso de uma forma elegante e rápida utilize o [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).

Comment: [Veja essa library](http://gf3.github.io/moment-range/) que tem exemplo de como fazer o calculo da diferença.

Comment: obrigado :) vou tentar já coloco aqui a solução

Comment: Nenhuma das respostas oferecidas o satisfaz?

Answer (score 10):

Bom dia.
Tente isso:

```
var date1 = new Date("7/11/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/12/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

**[Teste](http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/1/)**

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

Comment: Ótima solução, nenhum recurso externo.

Comment: Nenhuma explicação ou comentários no código

Comment: é verdade quer que eu explique?

Comment: Como faz para calcular data negativas. Exemplo hoje são 08/02/2020, se eu comparar com 10/02/2020 são +2 dias. Agora se eu comparar com 06/02/2020 deveria ser -2.

Answer (score 6):

No `JavaScript` as datas são valoradas conforme a quantidade de milissegundos apartir de `01/01/1970 00:00:00 GMT-0`. Ao subtrair uma data de outra você terá a diferença entre as datas em milissegundos.

O caminho mais simples é criar a data fim limite, baseada na data inicial. Considero este caminho o mais simples pois não envolve muito cálculo, uma vez que o JavaScript sempre gera uma data válida. Assim você pode simplesmente adicionar 3 meses à data inicial sem se preocupar com virada de ano ou ano bissexto, por exemplo.

## Comparando data fim com data limite

```
var dataInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("datainicio").value);
var dataFim = new Date(document.getElementById("datafim").value);
var limiteFim = new Date(dataInicio.getFullYear(),
                         dataInicio.getMonth() + 3,
                         dataInicio.getDate());

return !(dataFim > limiteFim);
```

## Calculando a diferença entre as datas

```
var dataInicio = new Date(document.getElementById("datainicio").value);
var dataFim = new Date(document.getElementById("datafim").value);
var diffMilissegundos = dataFim - dataInicio;
var diffSegundos = diffMilissegundos / 1000;
var diffMinutos = diffSegundos / 60;
var diffHoras = diffMinutos / 60;
var diffDias = diffHoras / 24;
var diffMeses = diffDias / 30;

return !(diffMeses > 3);
```

Comment: Sim, isso é verdade, mas como se verifica que elas estão entre um período de 3 meses?

Comment: Matemágica, meu amigo ;) Crie a data fim limite e compare com a data fim informada. Se a data fim limite for inferior está fora do período.  `if (end > start.setMonth(start.getMonth() + 3)) { return false; }`

Comment: Sim, eu sei como se faz, o AP é que não. O meu comentário era um convite a você melhorar a sua resposta de forma a torná-la mais completa..

Comment: Complementado ;)

Comment: n preciso de tanto :p

Comment: É JavaScript puro. Acho muito recorrer a uma biblioteca pra uma simples comparação de datas. Além de responder a pergunta eu dei uma explicação ampla permitindo que desta resposta se resolva outros problemas similares, não apenas se a diferença entre as duas datas é inferior ou igual a 3 meses.

Answer (score -1):

Código simples e funcional. Uso em vários sistemas meus:

```
$("#data-termino-ausencia").focusout(function(){
    var dtI = $(".data-inicio-ausencia").html().split('/');
    var dtF = $("#data-termino-ausencia").val().split('/');
    dia_I = dtI[0];
    dia_F = dtF[0];
    mes_I = dtI[1];
    mes_F = dtF[1];
    ano_I = dtI[2];
    ano_F = dtF[2];
    var calculoDia = dia_F - dia_I;
    var calculoMes = mes_F - mes_I;
    var calculoAno = ano_F - ano_I;

    if(calculoDia < "0" || calculoMes < "0" || calculoAno < "0"){
        BackOffice.alert("A data de término não pode ser anterior a data de inicio.", "Aviso", function(){
            $("#data-termino-ausencia").val("");
            $("#data-termino-ausencia").focus();
            BackOffice.closeModal('.modal', true);
        });
    } else if (calculoDia < "0" || calculoMes >= "0" || calculoAno >= "0") {       
        $(".outros-ausencia").focus();
    } else if (calculoDia <= "0" || calculoMes >= "0" || calculoAno >= "0") {
        $(".outros-ausencia").focus();<br>
    }
})
```