# Dúvida soma dia em Data JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estou com esta função em JS:

```js
now = new Date;
var dia_atual = now.getDate();
var atual_data = new Date(document.getElementById("<%= txtDataInicio.ClientID %>").value);
var dia_escolha = document.getElementById("<%= txtDiaVencimento.ClientID %>").value;
if ($("#<%=txtTipodePlano.ClientID %>").val() == "MENSAL") {
 if (parseInt(dia_escolha) > parseInt(dia_atual))
 {
  var total_dias = dia_escolha - dia_atual;
  var outraData = new Date();
  
  document.getElementById("<%= txtVencimentoC.ClientID %>").value = outraData.setDate(atual_data.getDate() + total_dias);
 }
}
```

Esse é o txtDataInicio:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDataInicio" runat="server" onBlur="limparDataInvalida(this);" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Aonde `txtDataInicio` é preenchido com a data atual, desta forma "16/10/2017".
Estou tentando fazer a conta, hoje quero somar o `total_dias`, porém não está funcionando, pois ele não reconhece o `txtDataInicio` como data. 
Por Exemplo: Se dia escolha for `20` e data atual foi `16`, `20 - 16 = 4`, onde deveria aumentar os 4 dias no `txtDataInicio`. Porém de todas as formas que eu tento, ele informa erro, não tenho muita experiência com datas no `JS`, 
Preciso acrescentar dias na data, porém não está pegando o formato correto. Agradeço.

Comment: "if ($("#<%=txtTipodePlano.ClientID %>").val() == "MENSAL") {" nessa linha acredito que você esta misturando javascript com jquery, é intencional?

Comment: @VictorPereira sim, pois é da forma que estou acostumada a fazer. Se tiver alguma sugestão melhor, obrigado.

Comment: "if (document.getElementById("#<%=txtTipodePlano.ClientID %>").value == "MENSAL") {" tenta substituir por js padrão, você pode não estar iniciando o jquery

Comment: Mas eu fiz o teste, colocando um valor padrão em txtVencimentoC, e ele entra no if certo, ele so não está fazendo a conta.

Comment: @marianac_costa será que essa pergunta te ajuda? [Calcular diferença entre duas datas para validar campos da data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86762/calcular-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas-para-validar-campos-da-data), veja que há uma cast no texto antes dele subtrair a diferença entre os dias das datas.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Diferença entre datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13046/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-datas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é o formato da data. Isso `new Date(document.getElementById("<%= txtDataInicio.ClientID %>").value);` vai lhe retornar nulo se o formato estiver em "16/10/2017",  você vai precisar formatar a data para poder fazer operações com ela.

```js
var now = new Date;
var dia_atual = now.getDate();
var atual_data = toDate('16/10/2017');

console.log(atual_data);

function toDate(texto){
  let partes = texto.split('/');
  return new Date(partes[2], partes[1], partes[0]);
}
```

Comment: Tentei dessa forma, porém ele aparece outra coisa no textbox q eu passaria os valores, não está nem em formato de data. Coloquei 22 no txtVencimento, está aparecendo esses números no txtVencimentoC: 1508675017862

Comment: Você está usando EJS? Conseguiria criar um exemplo verificavel (sem templates engines e com todos os componentes usados) @marianac_costa?

Comment: Fui verificar qual valor está em atual_data, está aparecendo esse valor "Thu Nov 16 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)" será que é por esse motivo que ele não consegue fazer a soma?