# Subtração com data - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google, planilha

Caros,

Preciso realizar o calculo de quantos dias restam para atingir a data prevista.

Estou obtendo os seguintes valores

```
var dataPrev = row[4]; //26/01/2018
var dataNaoFormat = new Date(); //22/01/2018
```

Estou realizando o seguinte calculo:

```
var sub = dataPrev - dataNaoFormat;
```

E o resultado é :

2.65807814E8

Tirando o formato cientifico, 26.580.781.400.000.000,00

Preciso que me retorne um número inteiro, nesse caso seria 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var row = data[i];
    var dataCarimbo = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(row[0]), "GMT", "dd/MM/yyyy");
    var dataForm = new Date(row[1]);
    var email = row[2];
    var dataPrev = row[4];
    var opcao = row[3];

    var timeDiff = Math.abs(dataPrev.getTime() - dataForm.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
```

Visto no tópico: [Calcular diferença entre duas datas para validar campos da data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86762/calcular-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-duas-datas-para-validar-campos-da-data)

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode utilizar nenhuma biblioteca js para tratar essas datas? Existe uma chamada momentJs https://ifpb.github.io/jaguaribetech/2016/09/01/moment-js/

Com ela voce consegue tratar isso de forma muito fácil.

Segue um exemplo em php também caso ajude:

```
$date = new DateTime("NOW");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";

//subtrai mês da data atual
$date = $date->sub(DateInterval::createfromdatestring('+ 1 month'));
echo 'Subtraindo 1 mês: '.($date->format('Y-m-d')).'<br>'; 

//Adiciona 1 mês a data
$date = $date->add(DateInterval::createfromdatestring('+ 1 month'));

//Recarrega mês atual
echo 'Adicionando 1 mês'.($date->format('Y-m-d')).'';
```