# Javascript/Jquery - Calculo de dias entre duas datas "DD/MM/YYYY"

Tags: javascript, jquery, data, matemática

Amigos, boa tarde... seguinte, o código abaixo, pega duas datas num calendário, no formato de

```
DD/MM/YYYY
```

```js
$('.two-calendars').on('pickmeup-change', function (evt) {
     var range = pickmeup(this).get_date('d-m-Y');
     if (range[0] != range[1]) {
         var label = pickmeup(this).get_date("d/m/Y");
         $('.search-tool .periodo .field-title').text(label[0] + " até " + label[1]);
        $('.search-tool .periodo input[name=periodo]').val(range);
      $('.search-tool .periodo').addClass("checked");
      $('.search-tool .periodo .header-title').html(range);
     }
```

Na ultima linha da função, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
$('.search-tool .periodo .header-title').html(range);
```

Para alterar um escrito em html, pelo valor da variável range. Pois a ideia é que exiba a quantidade de dias entre as duas datas selecionadas. Eu tentei, subtrair o `range[0]` pelo `range[1]`, e esconder os meses e anos, porém só funciona quando os meses são iguais. Acredito que minha dúvida seja mais matemática do que sobre programação. Se puderem me ajudar, agradeço.

Aqui o código que eu tentei fazer a subtração:

```
$('.search-tool .periodo .header-title').html(range[0] - range[1]);
```

No `prompt de comando` ele retorna como ilegal.

Comment: Aqui tem uma resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/86768/11482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inicialmente, devemos considerar que o javascript guarda datas como um número que representa a quantidade de milisegundos desde 1º de Janeiro de 1970, portanto, ao pegarmos esse número de milisegundos de duas datas diferentes, podemos fazer uma diferença entre esses valores e dividi-los pela quantidade de milisegundos de um único dia.

Primeiramente, para descobrirmos a quantidade de milisegundos de um dia, multiplicaremos a quantidade de horas, por minutos, por segundos e, finalmente, por milisegundos:

```
const DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

Agora, precisaremos criar as duas datas, o que implica em entrar com seus valores de dia, mês e ano para que sejam criadas e possamos recuperar seus valores em milisegundos. Os valores que usei servem apenas como exemplo, tendo em vista que a data deve ser passada dessa forma:

```
var D1 = new Date(2017, 11, 24);
var D2 = new Date(2018, 07, 15);

var mlsD1 = D1.getTime();
var mlsD2 = D2.getTime();
```

Obs.: Note que as datas se referem à, respectivamente: 24 de Dezembro de 2017 e 15 de Agosto de 2018. Precisamos prestar atenção no mês, que começam sua contagem em 0, portanto 0 se refere à Janeiro, 1 à Fevereiro e assim por diante.

Precisamos calcular agora a diferença entre as duas datas obtidas em milisegundos, para isso apenas faremos a subtração da data mais atual em milisegundos (mlsD2) pela data mais antiga (mlsD1):

```
var dif = mlsD2 - mlsD1;
```

Finalmente, para sabermos essa diferença em dias, apenas pegaremos esse valor e dividiremos pela constante criada no início, que representa a quantidade de segundos em um dia:

```
var qtdDays = dif / DAY;
```

Dessa forma teremos a quantidade de dias que se passaram entre as duas datas, sem contar o dia inicial. Para incluirmos o dia inicial poderemos somar um ao resultado da divisão ou, se quisermos apenas os dias intermediários, sem contar o dia inicial e o final, basta apenas subtrair um do resultado obtido. Espero que seja útil!

Comment: mano, serio... muito obrigado por ter explicado tudo tão foda assim... pq me deu uma puta noção de como funciona... vou tentar fazer aqui usando essa lógica! brigadão!

Comment: eu tinha tentado usar a lógica do link de uma outra pergunta que o rapaz postou acima, só que tipo, eu tava tentando fazer o cálculo direto, e não estava indo. achei muito mais foda desse jeito, tipo uma variável com o cálculo.

Answer (score 3):

Abaixo segue um exemplo de cáculo de diferença entre datas, retornando um inteiro em dias.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$('#calc').click(function(){
  var dt1 = $('#date1').val();
  var dt2 = $('#date2').val();
  
  $('#result').text(calcula(dt1,dt2))

});

function calcula(data1, data2){
  data1 = new Date(data1);
  data2 = new Date(data2);
  return (data2 - data1)/(1000*3600*24);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Subtrção da segunda pela primeira data:
<hr>
<label value="Primeira data: "><input id="date1" type="date">
<label value="Segunda data: "><input id="date2" type="date">
<input id="calc" type="button" value="Calcule">
<hr>
<label value="Resultado em dias:"><span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: mano! foda esse exemplo que você fez, brigadão ai, me ajudou muito a entender melhor como funciona na prática.

Comment: Luiz, estou com uma dúvida, não sei se você pode me ajudar...

Comment: mas assim, eu consigo pegar uma data 2018-08-23... mas se por acaso eu trabalhar com um formato de data "DD-MM-YYYY" eu teria que fazer um algoritmo para mudar a ordem dos valores, ou o cálculo também funcionaria? Pois os testes que eu fiz no prompt de comando, só consigo calcular no formato "YYYY-MM-DD" Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Conforme a [resposta do @Gabriel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/322682/112052), de fato com JavaScript nativo o único jeito é fazer as contas manualmente.

Caso você não tenha objeções quanto a usar uma biblioteca externa, recomendo o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com), que facilita **muito** a manipulação e os cálculos com datas.

Se suas datas estão no formato `DD/MM/YYYY`, basta fazer o parsing passando a `String` e o respectivo formato.

Por exemplo, `moment("30/01/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY")` vai criar uma data equivalente a 30 de janeiro de 2018. Repare que, diferente do JavaScrit nativo, aqui janeiro é mês 1 - se você usar `new Date`, conforme a [resposta do Gabriel explica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/322682/112052), janeiro é mês zero, então atenção neste ponto.

*O formato `"DD/MM/YYYY"` é descrito na [documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs/#year-month-and-day-tokens).*

Depois, para calcular a diferença em dias, basta usar [`diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/). O código fica assim:

```js
// 1 de janeiro de 2018
var inicio = moment("01/01/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY");
// 30 de janeiro de 2018
var fim = moment("30/01/2018", "DD/MM/YYYY");

// diferença entre as datas, em dias
var dias = fim.diff(inicio, 'days');
console.log(dias);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

O resultado é `29`, pois entre 1 de 30 de janeiro a diferença é de 29 dias.

Comment: mano, vc comentou uma parada dahora... pq eu tava tentando fazer calculo, ai quanto eu dei um "typeof" no comando, ele retornava como string, e não tem como calcular string, por isso dava "NaN"... não tenho problema nenhum em usar biblioteca externa ahhahaha vou meter o linkzão mesmo. vlw pela ajuda