# Como calcular a diferença de dias usando input do tipo "date"?

Tags: javascript, html5

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu tenho dois `input` do tipo `date`.

O que eu quero fazer em Javascript é calcular a diferença de dias do primeiro para o segundo, ou seja, se a pessoa colocar dia 19/09/2015 no primeiro `input` e 25/09/2015 no segundo, então é calculado quantos dias se passaram de 19 a 25, ou seja, 6 dias.

Como farei isso?

Obrigado.

Comment: [Diferença entre datas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13046/91)

Comment: Tentei seguir o exemplo, mas retorna-me "NAN"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método abaixo para isso, lembrando que você pode adicionar algumas verificações como: Se a data inicial é menor que a final ou se os valores estão preenchidos.

```
function calculaDiferenca(dataInicial, dataFinal) {

    /*gera um objeto do tipo Date com valor do input*/
    var date1 = new Date(dataInicial);        
    var date2 = new Date(dataFinal);

    console.log(date2.getTime());
    /*Subtrai a segunda data em milisegundos pela primeira e usa função abs para retornar o valor absoluto*/
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

    /*agora ele divide o valor da diferença das datas em milisegundos pela quantidade de milisegundos em um dia e usa ceil para 
    retorna o menor número inteiro*/
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

    alert(diffDays + ' dias');
}
```

Segue [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/751/).

Comment: Ó código não está a funcionar.

Comment: @Gonçalo está sim.. basta acessar o fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JS69L/751/, se quiser que mude algo só deixar nos comentarios =D

Comment: Estou vendo, no caso se quiser fazer onblour, para que assim que acabe de preencher, apareça logo um alert com o numero de dias sem precisar clicar em nada como faço?

Comment: a sim .. 1 minuto que implemento explicando pra você aqui :D

Comment: @Gonçalo, veja se é isso :D http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/JS69L/754/

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado!

Comment: @Gonçalo, não esqueça de marcar as respostas como resolvidas!

Comment: Como faço para marcar como resolvido?

Comment: @Gonçalo, debaixo da votação da resposta tem uma setinha/checkzinho basta clicar nele que a resposta está marcada como correta