# Erro de Código Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte código em javascript:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  function teste() {
    var date1 = document.getElementById("data");
    var date2 = document.getElementById("data2");
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    alert(diffDays);
  } < /script>
```

Em html tenho o seguinte codigo:

Reservar de: `<input type="date" name="data" id="data" />`

Até: `<input type="date" name="data2" id="data" onblur="teste()" />`

Eu gostaria de saber o motivo pelo qual eu a seguir de por a data nos inputs não aparece um `alert` dizendo o numero de dias.

Answer (score 1):

@Gonçalo, de acordo com o que havia conversado com você no outro [Post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87852/como-calcular-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-dias-usando-input-do-tipo-date), você terá que fazer dessa forma, após o foco do campo dataFinal ser retirado você pega o evento de `blur` e faz o calculo.

```
function calculaDiferenca(dataInicial, dataFinal) {
    var date1 = new Date(dataInicial);
    var date2 = new Date(dataFinal);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    alert(diffDays + ' dias');
}

(function() {

    var dataFinal = document.getElementById('dataFinal');

    dataFinal.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        var dataInicial = document.getElementById('dataInicial').value;

        if(!dataInicial) {
            alert('informe a data inicial e depois a final!');
            return;
        }

        var dataFinal = document.getElementById('dataFinal').value;

        if(!dataFinal) {
            alert('informe a data final!');
            return;
        }

        calculaDiferenca(dataInicial, dataFinal);
    });

})();
```

Segue o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buh159/JS69L/754/).

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Repara que quando usas `document.getElementById("data")` isso só por si não te dá o valor do `input`. Tens de ir buscar a propriedade `.value` para saber o valor.

Depois, uma vez que queres usar o `getTime()` tens de converter essa string que `document.getElementById("data").value` te dá de novo numa data. Nesse caso deves usar

```
var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById("data2").value);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
```