# como calcular a quantidade de dias com input do tipo date?

Tags: javascript, html, input

A minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu tenho dois input do tipo date.

O que eu quero fazer em Javascript é calcular a quantidade de dias do primeiro para o segundo, ou seja, se a pessoa colocar dataEntrada = dia 02/06/2018 no primeiro input e dataSaida = 06/06/2018 no segundo, então é calculado quantos dias se passaram em um novo input , ou seja, 4 dias.

Como farei isso?

Comment: [Diferença entre datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13046/), [Como calcular a diferença de dias usando input do tipo “date”? [duplicada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87852)

Comment: 6-2=4, e não 5 

Comment: Coloque o código que vc já tem, assim fica mais fácil.

Comment: Bem-vindo Marco Aurélio, se alguma resposta resolveu seu problema não deixe de marcá-la como aceita, veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: era falta de café cara kkkkkkkk, obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function calculaDiferenca(dataInicial, dataFinal) {

    /*gera um objeto do tipo Date com valor do input*/
    var date1 = new Date(dataInicial);        
    var date2 = new Date(dataFinal);

    console.log(date2.getTime());
    /*Subtrai a segunda data em milisegundos pela primeira e usa função abs para retornar o valor absoluto*/
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

    /*agora ele divide o valor da diferença das datas em milisegundos pela quantidade de milisegundos em um dia e usa ceil para 
    retorna o menor número inteiro*/
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

    alert(diffDays + ' dias');
}
```

Comment: agora q vi, meu chara kkkkkkkk

Comment: n sei se ja conseguiu a resposta pra sua dúvida, mas aí está

Answer (score 3):

```js
/******* função que recupera os valores dos inputs tipo date e
calcula a diferença entre eles. *******/

function difDias(){
    //instantaneos do objeto Date, veja explicação no final da resposta
    var dataUm = new Date(document.getElementById("dataUm").value);
    var dataDois = new Date(document.getElementById("dataDois").value);
    return parseInt((dataUm - dataDois) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function chamar(){
    document.getElementById("numeroDias").value = isNaN(difDias()) ? "Selecione a outra data" : difDias();  
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="textbox" id="dataDois" onchange="chamar()">

<input type="date" class="textbox" id="dataUm" onchange="chamar()"/>

<input type="text" class="textbox" id="numeroDias" name="numdays"/>
```

> O objeto Date tira um instantâneo do relógio interno do computador e retorna um objeto de data para esse instante.
>
> Internamente, o valor de uma instancia de objeto data é a hora, em milissegundos, desde zero hora de 1º de janeiro de 1970, no fuso horário Greenwich Mean Time - o ponto de referência padrão mundial para todas as conversões de hora.

Comment: Ou `document.getElementById("numeroDias").value = isNaN(difDias()) ? "Selecione a outra data" : difDias();`

Comment: @dvd, show de bola, o `Selecione a outra data`

Comment: Obrigado! deu certo aqui.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Creditos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627473/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

var umDia = 24*60*60*1000; // horas*minutos*segundos*milisegundos

var dataEntrada = new Date(2018,06,02);

var dataSaida = new Date(2018,06,06);

var difDias = Math.round(Math.abs((dataEntrada.getTime() - 
dataSaida.getTime())/(umDia)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente pegar a diferença entre as duas datas. Sendo `a` a data inicial e `b` a data final:

```js
// créditos
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript

var _MS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

// a and b are javascript Date objects
function dateDiffInDays(a, b) {
  // Discard the time and time-zone information.
  var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
  var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

  return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_DAY);
}

// test it
var a = new Date("2017-01-01"),
    b = new Date("2017-07-25"),
    difference = dateDiffInDays(a, b);
    
document.write(difference + " dias de diferença");
```