# Diferença entre datas em meses javascript

Tags: javascript, data, input

Galera quero ter a diferença de meses entre duas datas. Porem estou errando em alguma coisa. Quero digitar as datas nos inputs e o resultado aparecer em outro input.

```
var DateDiff = {

inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
    var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
    var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
    var d1M = d1.getMonth();
    var d2M = d2.getMonth();

    return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
}}
var dataInicio= document.getElementById("dataInicio");
var dataFinal = document.getElementById("dataFinal");
document.write("<br />Numero de <b>months</b> since "+dataInicio+": "+DateDiff.inMonths(dataInicio, dataFinal));
```

Comment: Vc tem algum exemplo?  Eu adptei esse porquê não sei javascript. Vc pode me ajudar?

Comment: Nem vi que era javascript malz ae... peri

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13046/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-datas
do @bacco

Comment: consegui, ae ...?

Comment: Ainda não. Tentei seguir o exemplo não funcionou. :(

Comment: peri, tho ver algo aqui

Comment: Tabom. Vou aguardar. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @ MagicHat nada. Assim que vc encontrar me avisa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vê se é isso...
O formato aceito é com barras : yyyy/mm/dd ou dd/mm/yyyy ou vírgulas yyyy,mm,dd

```html
<input type="date" id="dt1">Data 1</br>
<input type="date" id="dt2">Data 2</br>
<input type="text" id="result">Resultado</br>
<input type="submit" value="calcular" onclick="calcular();">
<script>
function calcular(){
var dt1 = document.getElementById("dt1").value; 
var dt2 = document.getElementById("dt2").value; 

var data1 = new Date(dt1); 
var data2 = new Date(new Date(dt2));
var total = (data2.getFullYear() - data1.getFullYear())*12 + (data2.getMonth() - data1.getMonth());
document.getElementById("result").value = total;
}
</script>
```

Qualquer coisa comenta que agente ajusta.

Se alguma das respostas, for valida, poderia validar, no ícone verde, abaixo das setas de avaliação..vlw;)

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado cara.

Comment: mano estou com um novo post. voce pode me ajudar? Porfavor. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/141073/carregar-valor-em-input-text-depois-de-selecionar-valor-em-select-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa instanciar as datas no padrão javascript.

```
var DateDiff = {

inMonths: function(d1, d2) {
d1 = new Date(d1);
d2 = new Date(d2);
var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
var d2Y = d2.getFullYear();
var d1M = d1.getMonth();
var d2M = d2.getMonth();

return (d2M+12*d2Y)-(d1M+12*d1Y);
}}
var dataInicio= document.getElementById("dataInicio").value;
var dataFinal = document.getElementById("dataFinal").value;
document.write("<br />Numero de <b>months</b> since "+dataInicio+": "+DateDiff.inMonths(dataInicio, dataFinal));
```

Sua data precisa estar em um padrão aceito pelo javascript "yyyy-mm-dd" ou "mm/dd/yyyy" , por exemplo,  para usar o new Date().

Comment: vc tem um modelo ou com input?

Comment: Quando vc recupera a data no input qual o formato que ela vem ?