# Carregar valor em input text depois de selecionar valor em select Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Quero carregar um valor em um input text depois de selecionar um valor em um select. Estou carregando o select normal. Quero carregar o input text usando javascript. No meu model faço uma comparação com os id. Os dados estão na mesma tabela.

Java Script:

```
<script>
    var base_url = '<? echo base_url() ?>';
    function busca_produtos(id_alug){
    $.post(base_url+"parcelas/get_parcelas", {
        id_alug : id_alug
    }, function(data){
        $('#parcelas').html(data);
    });
}</script>
```

Meu input select funcionando normal:

```
        echo "<select name='aquiller' id='id' class='form-control input-sm' onchange='busca_produtos($(this).val())'>";
```

Meu Controller:

```
 public function get_parcelas(){
    $parcelas = $this->sindico->get_parcelas();
    $option = "<option value=''></option>";
    foreach($parcelas -> result() as $linha) {
        $option .= "<option value='$linha->id_alug'>$linha->id</option>";
    }
    echo $option;
}
```

Comment: @MagicHat mano você pode da uma forcinha nesse problema?

Comment: Ramon você quer que quando um valor do select seja selecionado esse valor seja colocado em um input text é isso? Ou seria buscar outro valor baseado no valor do select?

Comment: Seria buscar outro valor  baseado no valor do select. Você viu meu código. Pode me dizer onde posso arrumar.

Comment: esta dando essa menssagem: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: A variável $parcelas -> result() é um array válido? pode ser isso

Comment: @RamonChaves creio que o comentário acima pode ser o ponto em questão, o foreach trabalha com arrays, e result() me parece um método.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que seu select já deveria ser escrito por completo na página, do jeito que está no código, parece que só no evento *change* que o select é montado.

Segue exemplo para buscar o valor baseado o select escolhido

```
<select id="opcoes">
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="valor">

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#opcoes").change(function(event) {
            var id_alug = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'buscar_produto.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {id_alug : id_alug},
            })
            .done(function(valor) {
                $("#valor").val(valor);
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <script>
  var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>';
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#opcoes").change(function(event) {
    var id_alug = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'base_url+"parcelas/get_parcelas"',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {id_alug : id_alug},
     })
     .done(function(valor) {
      $("#valor").val(valor);
     })
     .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
     });
   });
  });
 </script>

Comment: nao ta rodando passei os parametros do controller e nada

Comment: la na url o get_parcelas é o nome da função da minha controller

Comment: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Tem como a gente adotar esse modelo aqui?  http://www.dicascodeigniter.com.br/como-criar-um-select-dinamico/

Comment: Mas Invalid argument supplied for foreach() isso é erro no php, sua consulta está retornando dados? dá um  var_dump no $parcelas -> result() para ver o está sendo retornado.

Comment: Fernando não chega no model. Ele da brinca no javascript. Vc entra nesse link que te mandei. O código do cara ta normal. Mas no meu da pau. Porque eu quero mostrar no input

Comment: Da com console.log no retorno ou mande a mensagem de erro do javascript

Answer (score 0):

@fernandoandrade da uma olhada de como ficou porque no comentarios fica bagunçado.

```
<script>
    var base_url = '<?php echo base_url()?>';
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#opcoes").change(function(event) {
            var id_alug = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                    url: 'base_url+"parcelas/get_parcelas"',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id_alug : id_alug},
                })
                .done(function(valor) {
                    $("#valor").val(valor);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    console.log("error");
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: O $.post do código da pergunta funcionava? Será que é alguma coisa relacionado a forma de funcionamento do codeigniter, nunca usei ele, mas como vi uma requisição ajax respondi a pergunta. Você como está seu select na página, já vem completo quando carrega correto?

Comment: Sim o select ta funcionando normal. Vc vou a msg de erro que ta aparecendo o mim. O erro é no javascript

Comment: mande a mensagem de erro por favor.