# Como verificar quantos dias se passaram a partir de uma data em Javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Preciso verificar a quantidade de dias que se passaram desde o dia em que determinada tarefa foi criada, por exemplo, se eu inicio uma tarefa hoje eu recebo a seguinte data de volta:

`2017-08-30 11:38:52.168`

Eu preciso fazer um controle para que daqui a 04 dias, por exemplo, o usuário seja avisado que ele esta com uma tarefa atrasada, minha necessidade então, é saber como posso verificar via data do sistema se já se passaram os quatro dias, a lógica seria `dataAtual - dataCriacao = 4` ou `ou dataCricao + 4 = dataAtual` porém não estou conseguindo realizar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá uma olhada [nessa resposta do Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13050/80474)

Mas, pra facilitar:

```
function dateDiferencaEmDias(a, b) {
   // Descartando timezone e horário de verão
   var utc1 = Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate());
   var utc2 = Date.UTC(b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate());

   return Math.floor((utc2 - utc1) / ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) );
}
```

Onde, os parâmetros de entrada são as data inicial e final.

Comment: Deu certo desse modo