# Validação de período de data positivo dá erro de NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho isso no meu JS

```
var inicioFerias = new Date($("#txtInitialVacancies").val());
var fimFerias = new Date($("#txtFinalVacancies").val());

var utc1 = Date.UTC(fimFerias.getFullYear(), fimFerias.getMonth(), fimFerias.getDate());
var utc2 = Date.UTC(inicioFerias.getFullYear(), inicioFerias.getMonth(), inicioFerias.getDate());

        var diffDays = Math.ceil((utc1 - utc2) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 

alert("diff " + diffDays);
```

Acontece isso:

```
data final= 02/06/2010
data inicial = 08/06/2020
```

Diz que data final não pode ser menor que data inicial e retorna false, isso está correto. Agora se

```
data final = 31/07/2020
data inicial = 08/06/2020
```

Retorna um NaN no diffDays e não valida período de férias superior a 30. Já fiz com Math.floor mesma coisa. Com Math.abs não valida nada.

**Edit**

Tem um erro que peguei agora. Quando eu dou getDate() na data, deveria me retornar o dia da data e está me retornando o mês. Talvez esteja aí o problema

**Edit2**

Mudei para isso

```
var inicioFerias = new Date($("#txtInitialVacancies").val().split("/"));
var fimFerias    = new Date($("#txtFinalVacancies").val().split("/"));
var dateStart = inicioFerias.toLocaleDateString();
var dateEnd = fimFerias.toLocaleDateString();


var dd = (Date.parse(dateEnd) - Date.parse(dateStart)) / (1000*60*60*24);
alert("qdt " + dd);

var diffDays = dd;
```

E pego o seguinte. Quando a Data Final é menor que a Data Inicial, beleza, funciona, porém quando a Data Final é maior que a data Inicial, recebo um NaN

Comment: Qual é o valor retornado por `$("#txtInitialVacancies").val()` e `$("#txtFinalVacancies").val()`? Se forem strings no formato dd/mm/yyyy (como "31/07/2020"), aí pode dar `NaN` mesmo, já que o construtor de `Date` não aceita qualquer string como parâmetro...

Comment: @hkotsubo, mas quando a dataFinal é menor que a inicial ele valida corretamente. Isso é que eu não entendo. Por exemplo, na Data `$("#txtInitialVacancies").val()` eu tenho isso: `Thu Aug 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)`

Comment: O engraçado é que 08/06 deveria ser 8 de Junho, não 6 de Agosto. Como já comentado na sua outra pergunta, leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13046/5878. Ali tem explicado como calcular a diferença de datas. Por favor, tente ler e entender o que foi feito nas respostas.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, não sei porque, mas ele tá pegando o formato mes/dia/ano e não sei como inverter isso sem quebrar o formato date

Comment: O formato `dd/mm/yyyy` não existe na ISO e não é suportado pelo JS. Nós que usamos esse *erroneamente* formato.

Comment: mas eu dou um getDate() e me trás o mês e não dia. Usamos o datePicker aqui

Comment: É exatamente ai seu erro, quando você dá um getDate() ele já puxou a data no formato correto (como o nosso é errado), você deve informar o formato da data antes do new Date(). Ou seja, trate sua string antes.

Comment: Exatamente, leia sobre os parâmetros da classe `Date` e entenderá o problema. Já demos spoilers demais, não podemos estragar o final da história.

Comment: @LeonardoGetulio, no meu segundo edit eu dou um toLocaledateString. Quando vou calcular com a data final maior que a inicial, retorna um NaN. O contrário funciona corretamente

Comment: Mano, vamos lá, esquece a data, primeiro faz o seguinte: pega o valor do seu edit em string que vai tá no formato `dd/mm/yyyy` ex: `08/06/2020` e faz ela ficar em um formato bom para o javascript reconhecer, sugiro este `yyyy-mm-dd` ex: `2020-06-08`, depois disto você dá o parse: `new Date(variavelTratata)` ex: `new Date('2020-06-08')`. Se não fizer isto não vai dar certo, a não ser que utilize uma biblioteca de terceiros para isto.

Comment: O único formato de string que é garantido funcionar em todos os browsers do mesmo jeito é "yyyy-mm-dd", qualquer outro formato [será dependente do browser e não é garantido que funcione](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408168/112052). No caso de "31/07/2019", o Chrome (e não lembro se o Firefox também) interpreta como "mês/dia/ano", e como nesse caso o "mês" é 31, a data é inválida e ele retorna NaN. O jeito é gerar a string no formato correto, ou quebrar essa string, extrair os valores numéricos e passar para o construtor: `new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia)` (subtrai 1 do mês porque janeiro é zero)

Answer (score 3):

Se a data é no formato que você informou `08/06/2020`, então o problema está nas primeiras linhas, nenhuma das tuas implementações abaixo é válida para datas:

```js
var inicioFerias = new Date($("#txtInitialVacancies").val());
var inicioFerias = new Date($("#txtInitialVacancies").val().split("/"));
```

Não funcionam pois a interface de `new Date(data)` espera uma data no formato:

```js
new Date();//Atribui data e hora atual
new Date(ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto, segundo, milissegundo);
new Date(valor);//Inteiro em milisegundos
new Date(dataString);//String em alguns formato ISO-8601 (2020-06-08T00:00:00)
```

Referência: [Documentação Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Você pode alterar o formato da data de varias formas, eu usaria regex:

```js
var inicioFerias = new Date($("#txtInitialVacancies").val().replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$3-$2-$1"));
```

Se achar complexo de entender pode dar revert + join na tua segunda solução:

```js
var inicioFerias = new Date($("#txtInitialVacancies").val().split("/").reverse().join("-"));
```

Comment: Eu resolvi passando a data para MM-dd-yyyy, e então fazer o cálculo. Como eu não respondi e se a sua der certo, vou marcar sua resposta, AndreAntunesVieira. Estou no trem.