# Calculando datas (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, data

Estou tentando desenvolver um tipo de registro de Mod para meu Discord Bot.

*Ps: não acredito que seja necessário conhecimento de discord.js para resolução da pergunta*

Como funcionaria: O usuário com permissões de administrador iria esrever `modstats`, e o bot iria retornar uma tabela/embed com as informações de quando foi a última vez que um moderador usou um comando `ban/mute/kick/warn` *(já estão prontos)* da seguinte maneira:

```
warns (última semana): [número]
warns (último mês): [numero]
warns (ano inteiro): [numero]
```

Eu estava me perguntando como faria para que o bot registrasse o dia em que o último warn foi feito, e calculasse o intervalo de tempo entre o anterior. Pensei em algo como:

```
const warn = require('link_do_arquivo_de_warn.js')
const hoje = new Date(); // Data de hoje
const ultimaVez = new Date('2014-07-07'); // Outra data no passado

let calcular = new CalcularIntevaloDeDatas() // função de calcular que eu não faço muita ideia de como montar

if (message.content == warn) //caso algum mod dê um warn

{ 
db.data.banidos.push(hoje)
db.data.banidos[0]            //salva a data de hoje no banco de dados (essa parte não é muito importante. Estou usando um banco chamado LOWDB)
}

if (message.content == "modstats") { return calcular }

console.log(calcular)
```

Mas a questão é que não sei como calcular a diferença entre as datas salvas, digo, supondo que o moderador deu um `warn` há 3 dias (warn 1), e deu outro hoje (warn 2). Como faço o bot saber que houveram 2 warns há uma semana? Daí aplico a mesma lógica ao mês e ao ano...

*Nota: além de calcular as datas, devo também salvar o warn 2 como a ultima data, e o warn 1 como penultima (que ele não seja salvo mais como a última data), para que eu possa calcular o proximo warn a partir do warn 2 - e assim por diante.*

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Diferença entre datas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13046/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-datas)

Comment: Não responde, pois preciso também saber como posso salvar a última data como última, a anterior como penúltima, e assim por diante, de modo automático....

Answer (score 0):

Bastaria criar um `array`, já que você diz haver apenas três possibilidades. Então utilizar as soluções já mencionadas nos comentários.

---

```js
let r = {
  "semana": 0,
  "mes": 0,
  "sempre": 0
};

let now = new Date();

let dates = [
  now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), // semana
  now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 6), // semana
  now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 8), // mes 
  now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 34), // sempre
  now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 100), //sempre
  now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 130), //sempre
];

for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
  diff = (Math.floor((now - dates[i]) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)));
  let m = "semana";
  switch (true) {
    case diff > 30:
      m = "sempre";
      break;
    case diff > 7:
      m = "mes";
      break;
  }
  r[m]++;
}

console.log(r);
```

Comment: No caso, "now" é o "hoje" que eu coloquei em cima, certo?
Onde entraria a última data salva antes dessa nova?

Comment: Não há qualquer motivo para isso, se você já a a lista de datas, basta comparar a lista de datas. Ou, faltam detalhes na sua pergunta. O que pede é "[...] como calcular a diferença entre as datas salvas, digo, supondo que o moderador deu um warn há 3 dias (warn 1), e deu outro hoje (warn 2). Como faço o bot saber que houveram 2 warns há uma semana? Daí aplico a mesma lógica ao mês e ao ano...". No meu exemplo, o `dates` é a lista dos "warn", que terá as datas (do warn1 e do warn2). Se você quiser ignorar datas antigas, basta verificar se a data anterior é maior que a nova, é a mesma lógica.